# BrightCove with DTM in Dynamic Tag Management

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I am facing issue with the bright cove video events.
For bright cove video events – I am able to log video events in the console but unable to map it with Adobe Analytics.
Please see the screenshot below shows events logged into console when certain action has been taken by user on video Highlighted in Yellow:

Also, in DTM I have created the tag for the same under page load -Trigger rule- onload - open editor below mention code  i have shared.

```
try{
if(videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api')){
videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('play',function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
    console.log('play');
  var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();
  var vidDuration = myPlayer.mediainfo.duration;
  console.log('log'+ whereYouAt);
   console.log('log11'+ vidDuration);
  if(whereYouAt==(vidDuration/4)){
  }
   _satellite.notify("VIDEO - PLAY - "+myPlayer.mediainfo.name + ", "+whereYouAt, 3);
        var c = s_gi(_satellite.getVar("settings_aa_reportsuite")).Media;


});
videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('pause',function(){
     console.log('pause');

});
videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('ended',function(){
    console.log('ended');

});
videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('progress',function(){
    console.log('progress'); 
})};
}
catch(err){
console.log('error in:' + err);
}





_satellite.notify("@Load - Media Module - START", 3);


// set up Media module
s.loadModule("Media");


s.Media.autoTrack = false;
s.Media.trackUsingContextData = true;
s.Media.trackVars = s.linkTrackVars;
s.Media.trackEvents = "event21,event22,event23,event24,event41,event42,event43";
s.Media.trackMilestones="25,50,75";
s.Media.segmentByMilestones = true;


s.Media.contextDataMapping = {
  "a.media.name": "eVar21,prop21",
  "a.media.segment": "eVar22",
  "a.contentType": "eVar23",
  "a.media.timePlayed": "event21",
  "a.media.view": "event22",
  "a.media.segmentView": "event24",
  "a.media.complete": "event23",
  "a.media.milestones": {
    "25": "event41",
    "50": "event42",
    "75": "event43"
  }
};


s.Media.monitor = function (s, media){
  if (media.event == 'play' || media.event == 'pause') {
_satellite.notify("MEDIA MONITOR - event is "+media.event, 3);
    s.Media.track(media.name);
_satellite.notify("MEDIA MONITOR - just tracked for "+media.event, 3);
}

};

_satellite.notify("@Load - Media Module - END", 3);
```

It would be great if anyone can help us on that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the Video measurement script as well for our video player but I didn't work for me, so I went ahead and found an alternative for the same.
If you're using Adobe DTM to deploy Adobe Analytics, you can use direct call rules here. 
for example: You can call the methods provided by Bright Clove Player API and pass the values to it.

```
videojs('te-brightcove-trigger-video_html5_api').on('pause',function(){
     console.log('pause');
    _satellite.track("pause");
```

Create direct call rule and add condition string as 'pause' and fire the required events. The same solution can be built upon milestones and other video player events.

Comment: Hi, Pause, play and stop method are already defined in brightcove api. but there is not method call for milestones.how to track 25% and 50% milestones